# Comparison of input statements in java

Tags: java, performance, input, types, type-conversion

Two statements which more or less do the same job of inputting an int

```
int foo = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

and

```
int bar = Integer.parseInt(new Scanner(System.in).next());
```

Is there any performance difference between them..???????????

Comment: If you have trouble with the performance, try using an alternative to Scanner.

Answer (score 3):

The time it takes to blink is about 50 milli-seconds. The time to press a key is about the same. The difference between these statement will be far less than this and will be less than 0.002 milliseconds.

In short, I wouldn't worry about it.  Make it correct, clear and simple, and this is often the fastest as well.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't think you should be thinking in terms of efficiency here, especially since you seem to use it for a local variable, and you throw away the (newly created) `Scanner` in either case.

But if it's still of interest, I'd say that the performance difference is negligible, since the `Scanner.nextInt` ends with a

```
return Integer.parseInt(s, radix);
```

anyway.

If you need to parse several integers, I would say the best way to create a `Scanner` once, and reuse that instance:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int foo = scanner.nextInt();
int bar = scanner.nextInt();
// ...
```